# Upper bound for the number of generators of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H\leq G$ and $x\in G$. If $H$ is generated by at most $n$
>   elements, prove that $\langle H,x\rangle$ is generated by at most
>   $n+1$ elements.

This is intuitively obvious but when I try to write down my thoughts I get very confused.

Let $h_i$ be the generators of $H$. Then it is clear that $\langle h_1,...,h_n,x\rangle=\langle H,x\rangle$. If $\langle H,x\rangle=\langle g_1,...,g_m\rangle$ where $m>n+1$, then what? Any thoughts?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the problem. Consider a group $K$ and an integer $n$. The statement "$K$ is generated by at most $n$ elements" means "there exists a generating set of $K$ having at most $n$ elements". It does *not* mean "every generating set of $K$ has at most $n$ elements", that would be silly because the union of any generating set with *any* other subset is still a generating set.

Comment: For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the set $\{1\}$, and it is also generated by any subset that contains the set $\{1\}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher So does it suffice to show that $\langle h_1,...,h_n,x\rangle=\langle H,x\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ is generated by at most $n$ elements, there exist elements $h_1, \ldots, h_k \in H$ such that $\langle h_1,\ldots,h_k \rangle = H$ and $k \le n$. Also, $\langle H, x \rangle = \langle h_1,\ldots,h_k,x \rangle$ since both $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ hold. Thus there is a generating set for $H$ of cardinality $k+1$, i.e. $H$ is generated by at most $k+1$ elements.  Since $k+1 \le n+1$, the assertion follows.